# Show that every real matrix $B$ such that $AB = BA$ has the form $B = aI + bA + cA^2$ for some real numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Show that every real matrix $B$ such that $AB = BA$ has the form $$B = aI + bA + cA^2$$ for some real numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$.

**My attempt:** Let us consider the set $$V=\{B\in\mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) : AB = BA\}.$$ It is easy to prove that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$. Likewise, we can verify that $\mathcal{B}=\{I,A,A^2\}$ is a linear independent subset of $V$, because $x$, $Ax$, and $A^2x$ are linear independent vectors for $x=(1,0,0)^T$.

If we proved that the dimension of $V$ is $3$, then $\mathcal{B}$ would be a basis of that subspace, and the proof would be done.

However, I don't know how to show it. Can you give me an advice to do it, or tell me a different way to solve the problem?

Comment: You can prove that $B \mapsto AB-BA$ is a linear map.  If you can show that its image has dimension $6$, then you're done because you've shown that $\{I, A, A^2 \}$ is a linearly independent set within the kernel of this map.

Comment: A polynomial in a matrix $A$   automatically commutes with $A.$  If there is just one Jordan block for each eigenvalue, those are the only matrices that commute with $A.$ That is, when the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial coincide; one way this happens is when the eigenvalues are distinct.  If $f(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial, it has no repeated roots if the $\gcd(f,f') = 1.$

Comment: I like the dimension argument best but another option is: $Q^T AQ = D$ where the diagonal has 3 distinct elements.  Then $AB = BA\implies Q^TAQQ^TBQ=DQ^TBQ=Q^TBQ D$ and by direct calculation all off diagonal elements of $Q^TBQ$ are zero, i.e. $B$ is symmetric.  Spectral theorem + interpolation arguments tell you that $B$ can be written as a polynomial of $A$ and the minimal polynomial of $A$ (or Cayley Hamilton) tells you that $A^3$ is a linear combination of $\{I, A, A^2 \}$, so by induction this is also true for $A^k$ for $k\geq 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_0 = (1, 0, 0)^T$.  You already showed that $v_0$ is a cyclic vector for $A$ (i.e. $\{v_0, A v_0, A^2 v_0\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.)

So for any $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ there exists a degree-2 polynomial $f_w$ such that $f_w(A) v_0 = w$.  Since $B$ commutes with $A$ we have $$Bw = B f_w(A) v_0 = f_w(A) B v_0 = f_w(A) f_{B v_0}(A) v_0 = f_{B v_0}(A) f_w(A) v_0 = f_{B v_0}(A) w$$
Therefore $B = f_{B v_0}(A)$.